# How to delete the element which matches filter within the list in object of JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter

Sorry for my French and stupid question, but i need to DELETE some elements in JSON file while I don't now anything in JSON and JS

There is the structure:
`

```
{ "questions": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "quizId": 1,
        "question": "Какому автомобилю разрешается остановка в зоне действия этих знаков?",
        "correctAnswer": 4,
        "image": "1.jpg",
        "answers": [
            "Красному.",
            "Обоим автомобилям.",
            "Ни одному.",
            "Ни одному.",
            "Желтому, обозначенному опознавательным знаком \"Инвалид\".",
            "-"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "quizId": 1,
        "question": "По каким направлениям из числа обозначенных стрелками разрешается движение?",
        "correctAnswer": 4,
        "image": "2.jpg",
        "answers": [
            "Только по направлению А.",
            "Только по направлению Б.",
            "Только по направлению В.",
            "-",
            "-",
            "-."
        ]
    } 
]
}
```

And I need to find the elements within answers array which equals to `"-"` and delete it.

So output should be:

```
{ "questions": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "quizId": 1,
        "question": "Какому автомобилю разрешается остановка в зоне действия этих знаков?",
        "correctAnswer": 4,
        "image": "1.jpg",
        "answers": [
            "Красному.",
            "Обоим автомобилям.",
            "Ни одному.",
            "Ни одному.",
            "Желтому, обозначенному опознавательным знаком \"Инвалид\".",
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "quizId": 1,
        "question": "По каким направлениям из числа обозначенных стрелками разрешается движение?",
        "correctAnswer": 4,
        "image": "2.jpg",
        "answers": [
            "Только по направлению А.",
            "Только по направлению Б.",
            "Только по направлению В."
        ]
    } 
]
}
```

I tried to solve the problem, but unsuccessfully.
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Read the file, parse the data, process it, serialize the data and write the file.

Comment: This is pretty easy, but I don't know how to manage with JSON in JS. Can you write the answer in JS?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't be afraid to share the best code you got so far. Not only is mandatory (if implies some), it could also give you an advantage in understanding where you made a mistake, and it helps us to better understand the question and the real issue. Please, take a [tour], [edit] with a [mcve].

Comment: What step are you struggling with? You manage JSON in JS with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: I tried to convert it to array and filter the array by "-" and splice it. But unfortunately it is not working. Honestly, I am not JS coder so I cannot understand fully how to manage things. So I would be happy if you help me to resolve my problem

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform. If you're looking for a code writing service, you should consider hiring a paid freelancer. If you have a specific programming question, you should add it to the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this task, you could use some server-side scripting, I recommend NodeJS as it is directly related to JS.

You can see the documentation here: https://nodejs.dev/en/

Within the NodeJS project, you will have to use the File System module
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Having the above configured, the code would be as follows:

```
import fs from "fs"
const file_path = “YOUR_JSON_FILE_PATH”

let json_file_content = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file_path).toString());

  for (let i in json_file_content.questions) {
    json_file_content.questions[i].answers = 
    json_file_content.questions[i].answers.
    filter(answer => (answer != "-" && answer != "-."))
  }
 
fs.writeFileSync(file_path, JSON.stringify(json_file_content));
```

The above code can be described as follows:

- The FileSystem module is imported
- A constant is created which contains the path where your .json file is located
- We create a variable “json_file_content” which will contain the content of your .json file

To get this content, do the following:

- Get the content of your file using **readFileSync**
- This content is converted to string type using **toString**
- Subsequently, it is converted to JSON using **JSON.parse**

Having the json in a variable, simple JS code can now be applied, Inside that code what is happening is this:

- All **questions** contained in the object are iterated
- For each question, their **answers** are accessed
- The answers are filtered, eliminating those that are equal to "-" and "-."

Finally:

- The filtered json is converted to a string
- The new string (JSON) is written into your file using **writeFileSync**